# DataTables export CSV with html Tag

Tags: html, datatables

DataTables.net Here facing issue while export into csv only generating plain Text and Ignoring html tag like

```html5
<b></b>, <img src="">
```

how to include html tag too in export

Comment: You can't format CSV content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look at the docs -> **https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()**

Your html is removed because `stripHtml` by default is `true`. You can change that through `exportOptions` / `exportData` :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    exportOptions: { stripHtml: false } 
  }]
})
```